# init script that run a socket continuously

Tags: python, init-script, socket

I run my script(socket) as daemon with init-script :

```
   #!/bin/bash



### BEGIN INIT INFO
 # Provides:          sock_serv
 # Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
 # Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $remote_fs
 # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
 # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
 # Short-Description: sock_servservice
 # Description:       Run sock_serv service
 ### END INIT INFO

 # Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
 case "$1" in
   start)
     echo "Starting sock_serv..."
     if sudo -u root bash -c 'cd ~/mypath/ && python3 sock_serv.py &> /dev/null &' ; then
       echo "OK"
     else
       echo "Error: can't start "
     fi
   ;;
stop)
   echo "Stopping sock_serv..."
   if sudo -u root bash -c 'cd ~/mypath/ && python3 stop_sock_serv.py &>/dev/null &'; then
   # sleep 2
      echo "OK"
   else
      echo "Error: can't stop "
   fi
   ;;
   *)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/sock_serv {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

I use in `sock_serv` loop wiht Module `Select` to receive Message from different client.

I  can run my `sock_serv`, but after hours the `sock_serv` listen to any port( is stoped)

when I run `service sock_serv status` bevor and after sock_serv is stoped I get :

```
     sock_serv.service - LSB: sock_serv service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sock_serv; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-10-12 16:06:56 CEST; 23h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
     Tasks: 0 (limit: 2301)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/sock_serv.service


    Oct 12 18:08:10 sam sudo[1042]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
   Oct 12 18:08:10 sam sudo[1045]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root/mypath; USER=root ; COMMAND=/root/mypath/otherScript.py 
   Oct 12 18:08:10 sam sudo[1045]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

   Oct 12 18:08:10 sam sudo[1045]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

i want that the sock_serv still running continously. Thanks

Comment: I would try to figure out why `sock_serv.py` is exiting.

Comment: If that's not an option, you automatically restart it when it crashes. One way is to use systemd with `Restart=on-failure`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,. Where I put this line `Restart=on-failure` ?

Comment: @Mikel , I check logfile nothing found, just what i get from `service sock_serv status `

Comment: I found this error `Oct 12 17:05:51 sam kernel: [   10.447716]  wireguard: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel` in `kernel.log` at same when myservice is exited